# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving the following error in Chrome's Console while using a modal overlay jquery plugin called "Fallr."

> Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'fallr'

It cites line 43 of another .js file that I have that leverages the Fallr framework, and the several lines before, during, and after this line are below.  Line 43 is the first instance of `$.fallr('show', {`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output) {
        if (output.return_val === 1) {
            $.fallr('show', {
                buttons: {},
                content: '<h4>Yay!</h4><p>Your link has successfully been shared.</p>',
                position: 'center',
                autoclose: 3000,
                icon: 'check'
            });

        } else {

            $.fallr('show', {
                buttons: {},
                content: '<h4>Oops!</h4><p>Your link was not posted.</p>',
                position: 'center',
                autoclose: 3000,
                icon: 'error'
            });

        }
    }
});
return false;
});
});​
​
```

How can I fix this error?  It is causing chronological issues with all of the buttons on my page, whereby the Fallr method stops firing for one or two buttons once certain other buttons are pressed.

Comment: Are you sure the plugin was loaded correctly?

Comment: check your console for a 401/403/404 on your include of the plugin script.

Comment: Yes, the plugin works for the one button I have tied to it, and works in sequence (ie I keep pressing it without loading the page and it fires a modal overlay on the screen.)  The second I press a few other jquery buttons on my page, it renders the Fallr modal overlay futile.  The button Fallr is tied to still works, but it doesnt trigger the modal overlay.

Comment: did you close the if-condition correctly?

Comment: @jbabey I include it at top of the page, but is it possible I have included it in the incorrect order?  Should it be before or after other types of scripts?

Comment: @JohnDoe Check my edit up top where I include the rest of the script so you can tell me if I closed it correctly.  This could be an issue...but i think I closed it correctly....

Comment: is there any particular reason you aren't using the more standard jquery dialog?

Comment: @jbabey Sorry, I am new at this to some degree...what would be more standard?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ on a side note, paying money for some javascript is laughable :P

Comment: @jbabey I suppose if you know how to code Javascript it would be.  For beginners, I write it off to an education expense, much like a course or a book.  But I appreciate you laughing at my methods.  Certainly makes me feel better about my javascript error above!